# Encoding problems on a VPS Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, email, character-encoding, editors, vps

This is greasy. I've checked this only with Polish characters. There's a virtual machine I SSH into. The only exception is when I type something in my terminal. Then it can `echo` it right. And there's a positive variation on this. I copied a few Polish chars from my laptop with this command:

```
cat pl | ssh tomas@$do 'cat > pl'
```

This are the chars:

```
źćółęąŹĆÓŁĘĄ
```

When i `cat` it in the SSH session, it prints correctly. But when I make of it `index.html` in Apache, I get this:

```
ÅºÄ‡Ã³Å‚Ä™Ä…Å¹Ä†Ã“ÅÄ˜Ä„
```

I also can't use `vim` nor `nano`. **UPDATE:** I forgot the strongest trigger to ask this question was mail, as I'm working on this now. The mails arrive garbled. It's Postfix. I've been looking for similar issues and configs, but found nothing relevant so far.

These are the locales there:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_TIME=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_NAME=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

After I'd set in the site's config in Apache:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

the page prints correctly. This is a likely hint. And Sato Katsura may be right in the comments.

Comment: Did you set encoding in the web pages?  Did you configure Apache to negotiate the correct encodings?  Did you configure your browser to negotiate the correct encodings?  Encodings in web pages have nothing to do with your locales, you know.

Comment: @SatoKatsura I think you should add that as an answer, because it is almost certainly the problem here. The HTML needs to know the encoding - either through explicitly setting it in the file or by setting a default one in Apache.

Comment: @SatoKatsura No I didn't. And this was the last point, though maybe not to the point. I might have composed the question better. This is a lesser problem at the moment. What about the text editors?

Comment: Well, the obvious suspects: are your local locales different in any way from the remote ones?  Are you using 8-bit-clean terminals? etc.

Comment: @SatoKatsura They only differ in `LANGUAGE=en_US`. This is set on the client side and unset on the remote. And they're the same Ubuntu 16.04. I don't know how about the 8-bit-clean terminals. I normally use the GNOME Terminal and now just checked that X Term doesn't help with Vim. Are they 8-bit-clean?

Comment: @SatoKatsura I forgot the biggest pain was mail, as that's what I'm working on at the moment. The mails come over garbled. I need to add this to the question. I looked for configs and answers, and nothing on the horizon.

Comment: There are a lot of settings to control all these, scattered all over the place.  Vim f.i. has `encoding `, `termencoding`, `fileencoding`, `fileencodings` (not the same as the previous one :)), and a few others I can't remember right now.  Maybe if you'd ask about a single problem at a time and describe exactly what that problem is, your question would actually be answerable...

Comment: @SatoKatsura That's the thing. It's hard to explain how these separate issues may not be related. Couldn't it be a package or library from the realm of GUI that's causing this? I **guess** the server is headless.

Comment: So you're basically asking a riddle: what could possibly break locales, at the same time, in some unspecified superset of Vim and web browsing.  Then the answer (or at least my answer) is: who cares?  Perhaps some Ubuntu maintainer can answer that.